# trailling value #015 getting appended in variable in shell script

Tags: shell, sh

I am new to shell scripting and facing some issue.
When i am trying to read a value from properties file and printing it, it is showing correctly but when i append it with some string it also appends #015 with it.
For example:
my properties file:

```
first_name=Ram
```

i am using this in my shell script:

```
last_name=Sharma
name=${first_name}
echo "name ${name}"
fullname=${first_name}_${last_name}
echo "fullname ${fullname}"
```

Here the name is printed correctly as- **name Ram**
but fullname is printed like this **fullname Ram#015_Sharma** but it should be **fullname Ram_Sharma**

Comment: `dos2unix yourscript.sh` should fix the error. That is probably because of DOS line endings.